# Ubuntu 20.04 install python shout (python3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.6, ubuntu-20.04

https://pypi.org/project/python-shout/#files

Well, I tried:

```
python3.6 setup.py build
```

But I got this message:

```
Using PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
pkg-config and shout-config unavailable, build terminated
```

```
main# pip3 install python-shout
Collecting python-shout
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4a/d9/a845873d3fbf57cfecfa88e20eae77ef93f1a6bc68d9e092c8e020d96b88/python-shout-0.2.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Using PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/lib/pkgconfig
    pkg-config and shout-config unavailable, build terminated

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-oqd340si/python-shout/
You are using pip version 18.1, however version 20.2b1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

Same error from: https://icecast.org/download/

Same error from: https://pypi.org/project/python-shout3/#files

Any help would be useful.

Comment: @NiklasMertsch i tried. no change.

Comment: Try installing `pkgconfig` i.e. `sudo apt-get install -y pkg-config` Also make sure you have `libshout` and any development packages it has?

Comment: Tried with no luck

Comment: Is `libshout` installed? Usually the message indicates it has a problem determining the `libshout` library correctly (for which it also needs `pkgconfig`'s help). The doc https://pypi.org/project/python-shout/ also says: `libshout3` and `libshout3-dev` must be installed before installing the package itself.

Comment: @Nishant `sudo apt-get install -y libshout3 -dev` solved the issue. Many thanks!

Comment: Nice. Read the docs :xD so that pre-requsistes are not missing.